# How to create sharepoint alerts on the single item for item-level permission?

Tags: alert, item-level-permissions

I've got a document library and in this library, each document has different permission and some users are limited. So, when a document updates, I want to alert only the users that have permission. In other words I want to use alert item-level permission.

Comment: Are you talking about creating alert manually?  You can set alert on the particularly document/time.

Comment: I tried to do this "Alert Me" section. But it is about all library changes? so how?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the alert works only in items of which you have visibility, so you could set alerts on the whole list and the permission models will sort out if to send out emails to who. I have tried in the past to set alerts on people who were NOT in the permissions of the site and they never received any alert.

Comment: so, for example. We have got many groups like Group A, Group B ,Group C. And We have got a library called "Table". And i set an alert on the ribbon, so what will i write "Send Alerts To" space? so, will i set alerts with different titles for each group?

Comment: alerts are always PERSONAL, you need to put people's names, that field does not accepts names of groups

Comment: @susan are you sure about this as i see I can set alert on a particular group (even an AD group)?

Comment: I think for domain groups , an alert can be set. If you know email address of group , you can set an alert. It is visible.

Comment: @f_gulay yes that's correct.  I have updated my answer confirming you can set alerts for users with read permissions

Comment: The fact that you can set an alert does not mean that the alerts will be sent. The alert is personal and as far as I remember no version of Sharepoint was capable of setting alerts for groups, SP groups or AD groups, imagine you have 80k people, do you think if you select 'Everybody' it will set an alert on 80k people? Not possible, not even if your pool of employees is 100 (I have tried it and I ended up setting up alerts on single people)

Comment: At least SharePoint Online can do.  I haven't test with with 80K users.  Also the fact that the fields says 'Users' and description 'email addresses with semicolons' suggests you can set multiple users.

Comment: Multiple users is not the same thing as groups. Adding 1 or more emails is different than adding a SP, AD or o365 group.

Answer (score 1):

You can set alert on a document or an item.  Please ensure that particular item is select before setting alert.  A very good tutorial is available [here](http://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-alerts/)

**Select the item** you would like to set an alert:

[image]

**Note the title of the document**

[image]

I have tested setting an alert to a user with only 'Read' permission and this user did receive an email confirming the item has changed.  I tested this on the SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a workflow which is triggered by an item being modified.

You can target the email to be sent to specific Sharepoint User Groups.

Alerts are pretty basic and you can not do much with them, whereas a workflow is more flexible.

It might be worthwhile to think about changing the way the document library or perhaps Sharepoint Site works.  Can the individual permissions on each item be removed?  Perhaps defining Sharepoint Groups would allow you to achieve the same outcome without needed to make unique permissions on each item?

Perhaps you could consider classifying the documents by creating a choice column - then tag each item according to a property.  For instance if the documents are used by different departments, tag each document with the department name.  Then customise a workflow to reference the choice (e.g. if Department field = Accounts, email the Accounts Group).